# Sorting Gameobjects and set their SiblingIndex in Hierarchy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a friendsystem and want to sort it by the Users Worldrank (via PlayFab).

I want the best at the Top and the worst at the bottom.

I tried it with the following Script

```
private void sortfriendlist()
    {
        GameObject[] Friendcolumns = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Friendcolumn");

        for (int i = 0; i < Friendcolumns.Length; i++)
        {
            //If ranked
            if (Friendcolumns[i].name.Substring(0, 1) != "F")
            {
                //Set Sibling (Rank)
                int rank = int.Parse(Friendcolumns[i].name.Substring(0, 1));
                Friendcolumns[i].transform.SetSiblingIndex(rank);

            }
            //If unranked
            else
            {
                Friendswithoutrank[i] = Friendcolumns[i];
            }
        }

        Debug.Log(Friendswithoutrank.Length + " Friends without Rank");

        for(int i = 0; i < Friendswithoutrank.Length; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log(Friendswithoutrank[i].name + " has no Rank");
            Friendcolumns[i].transform.SetAsLastSibling();
        }
    }
```

But that doesnt work as you can see here

[image: Friendlist ingame]

First Im getting all Friends and store them in an Array. After that Im checking if the Player even has a Rank by checking if there is an "F" at the beginning of the GameObjects Name (Friends without a Rank have no Ranknumber in front of the Gameobject Name so the Name start with an "F"). Than Im getting the Rank of the Friend and set the SiblingIndex to the Rank. So normally it should be sorted now as i think. But that idea doesn´t seem to work.

If you have any idea how to fix it or make it better please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorting can actually be done much easier using Linq (also see [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-do-i-arrange-childrens-in-heirarchy-in-order-using-recttransform-setsiblingindex-w.446941/)):

```
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

private void sortfirendlist()
{
    var Friendcolumns = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Friendcolumn");

    // Use linq to get the Objects with and without Rank (not starting / starting with "F")
    // This works a bit similar to sql code
    // -> if the "Where" returns true -> object stays in the list
    // using string.StartsWidth which is a 
    // better choice for what you are doing with Substring(0,1)== ...
    var withoutRank = Friendcolumns.Where(obj => obj.name.StartsWith("F"));
    var withRank = Friendcolumns.Where(obj => !obj.name.StartsWith("F"));

    // Sort the ranked by name (again using Linq)
    var rankedSorted = withRank.OrderBy(go => go.name);

    // Now we have our ordered arrays -> we just have to apply that to the scene

    // set sibling index for the ranked 
    foreach (var t in rankedSorted)
    {
        // I simply send them one by one to the bottom
        // => when we are finished they are all sorted at the bottom
        t.transform.SetAsLastSibling();
    }

    // Do the same for the unranked to also send them to the bottom

    Debug.Log(withoutRank.Length + " Friends without Rank");

    foreach (var t in withoutRank)
    {
        Debug.Log(t.name + " has no rank");
        t.transform.SetAsLastSibling();
    }

    // Now the object we sent to the bottom first 
    // (first element in withRank) should be on top and everything sorted below it
}
```